# Is there a floating point value of x, for which x-x == 0 is false?

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

In most cases, I understand that a floating point comparison test should be implemented using over a range of values (abs(x-y) < epsilon), but does self subtraction imply that the result will be zero?

```
// can the assertion be triggered?
float x = //?;
assert( x-x == 0 )
```

My guess is that nan/inf might be special cases, but I'm more interested in what happens for simple values.

**edit:**

I'm happy to pick an answer if someone can cite a reference (IEEE floating point standard)?

Comment: You have accepted the question, but please read also my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686644/is-there-a-floating-point-value-of-x-for-which-x-x-0-is-false/2687323#2687323. It can clear (I hope) and close your question.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As you hinted, `inf - inf` is `NaN`, which is not equal to zero.  Similarly, `NaN - NaN` is `NaN`.  It is true, however, that for any finite floating-point number `x`, `x - x == 0.0` (depending on the rounding mode, the result of `x - x` might be negative zero, but negative zero compares equal to `0.0` in floating-point arithmetic).

**Edit:** it's a little tricky to give a clear standards reference, because this is an emergent property of the rules set forth in the IEEE-754 standard.  Specifically, it follows from the requirement that operations defined in Clause 5 be correctly rounded.  Subtraction is such an operation (Section 5.4.1 "Arithmetic operations"), and the correctly-rounded result of `x - x` is a zero of the appropriate sign (Section 6.3, paragraph 3):

> When the sum of two operands with
>   opposite signs (or the difference of
>   two operands with like signs) is
>   exactly zero, the sign of that sum (or
>   difference) shall be +0 in all
>   rounding-direction attributes except
>   roundTowardNegative; under that
>   attribute, the sign of an exact zero
>   sum (or difference) shall be −0.

So the result of `x - x` must be `+/- 0`, and therefore must compare equal to `0.0` (Section 5.11, paragraph 2):

> Comparisons shall ignore the sign of zero.

**Further Edit:** That's not to say that a buggy compiler couldn't cause that assert to fire.  Your question is ambiguous; there is no finite floating point number `x` such that `x - x == 0` is false.  However, that's not what the code that you posted checks; it checks whether or not a certain expression in a C-style language can evaluate to a non-zero value; in particular, on certain platforms, with certain (ill-conceived) compiler optimizations, the two instances of the variable `x` in that expression might have *different* values, causing the assertion to fail (especially if `x` is the result of some computation, instead of a constant, representable value).  This is a bug in the numerics model on those platforms, but that doesn't mean that it can't happen.

Comment: fantastic, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: +1. Whodathunk the internet could be this precise. (Not to take anything from you personally, Stephen.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: it helps to have spent a few months as the editor of the 754 draft standard.  Without that background, I wouldn't know where to look for this stuff.

Comment: Could you comment my code example from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686644/is-there-a-floating-point-value-of-x-for-which-x-x-0-is-false/2687323#2687323. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, neither C nor C++ _requires_ 754. Perhaps the question should be retagged ?

Comment: Also, if x is global and volatile, the compiler might read it twice, and multithreading could interfere.

Comment: Oh the days when the internet was filled with this quality of information... 1993. Far less information, but high quality :-)

Answer (score 4):

If the representation is transformed (for example from 64-bit memory format to 80-bit internal register format on x86) I would expect that the assertion could possibly fire in some circumstances.

Comment: As the question is worded, this case is probably impossible. But `x=a+b; assert(x-(a+b)==0)` might trigger it.

Comment: I think this is a key thing to be concerned with - the expression `x - x` is unlikely to be be used in real code (why would you?), But subtracting (or comparing) a variable's value with an expression that might have produced that value might happen, and might produce unexpected results because of how the compiler might handle precisions of intermediate values.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497825/gcc-problem-with-raw-double-type-comparisons for an example that's probably not too unlike something that might happen in the real world.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, apart from the special cases `x-x` will always be 0. But `x*(1/x)` will not always be 1 ;-)

Comment: Isn't he asking for the special cases?

Comment: @Frank - Yes, but he's ignoring the two special cases ypnos is referring to (`inf` and `NaN`).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, self-subtraction should always result in zero, except for special cases.

The problem occurs where you add, subtract, multiply or divide before a comparison where the exponent and mantissa are adjusted.  When the exponents are the same, the mantissas are subtracted, and if they're the same, everything ends up at zero.

http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/

Answer (score 3):

My answer on the main question: "Is there a floating point value of x, for which x-x == 0 is false?" is: at least floating point implementation on Intel processors makes **NO** arithmetic underflow in "+" and "-" operations and so you will be not able to find an x for which x-x == 0 is false. The same is true for **all processors which supports IEEE 754-2008** (see references bellow).

My short answer on another your question: if (x-y == 0) is exactly so safe as if (x == y), so assert(x-x == 0) is OK, because **no arithmetic underflow will be produced** in x-x or (x-y).

The reason is following. A float/double number will be hold in memory in the form mantissa and binary exponent. In the standard case mantissa is normalized: it is >= 0.5 and < 1. In `<float.h>` you can find some constants from IEEE floating point standard. Interesting now for us are only following

```
#define DBL_MIN         2.2250738585072014e-308 /* min positive value */
#define DBL_MIN_10_EXP  (-307)                  /* min decimal exponent */
#define DBL_MIN_EXP     (-1021)                 /* min binary exponent */
```

But not everybody knows, that you can have double numbers **less then** DBL_MIN. If you makes arithmetical operations with numbers under DBL_MIN, this number will be ***NOT*** normalized and so you works with this numbers like with integers (operation with mantissa only) without any "round errors".

**Remark**: I personally try not use words "round errors", because there are **no errors** in arithmetical computer operations. These operation are only not the same as +,-,* and / operations with the same computer numbers like floating number. There are **deterministic operations** on the subset of floating point numbers which can be saved in the form (mantissa,exponent) with well defined number of bits for each. Such subset of floats we can named as *computer floating number*. So the result of *classical floating point operation* will be *projected* back to the computer floating number set. Such projecting operation is deterministic, and have a lot of features like if x1 >= x2 then x1*y >= x2*y.

Sorry for the long remark and back to our subject.

To show exactly what we have if we operate with numbers less then DBL_MIN I wrote a small program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

void DumpDouble(double d)
{
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *)&d;
    int i;

    for (i=1; i<=sizeof(d); i++) {
        printf ("%02X", b[sizeof(d)-i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

int main()
{
    double x, m, y, z;
    int exp;

    printf ("DBL_MAX=%.16e\n", DBL_MAX);
    printf ("DBL_MAX in binary form: ");
    DumpDouble(DBL_MAX);

    printf ("DBL_MIN=%.16e\n", DBL_MIN);
    printf ("DBL_MIN in binary form: ");
    DumpDouble(DBL_MIN);

    // Breaks the floating point number x into its binary significand
    // (a floating point value between 0.5(included) and 1.0(excluded))
    // and an integral exponent for 2
    x = DBL_MIN;
    m = frexp (x, &exp);
    printf ("DBL_MIN has mantissa=%.16e and exponent=%d\n", m, exp);
    printf ("mantissa of DBL_MIN in binary form: ");
    DumpDouble(m);

    // ldexp() returns the resulting floating point value from
    // multiplying x (the significand) by 2
    // raised to the power of exp (the exponent).
    x = ldexp (0.5, DBL_MIN_EXP);   // -1021
    printf ("the number (x) constructed from mantissa 0.5 and exponent=DBL_MIN_EXP (%d) in binary form: ", DBL_MIN_EXP);
    DumpDouble(x);

    y = ldexp (0.5000000000000001, DBL_MIN_EXP);
    m = frexp (y, &exp);
    printf ("the number (y) constructed from mantissa 0.5000000000000001 and exponent=DBL_MIN_EXP (%d) in binary form: ", DBL_MIN_EXP);
    DumpDouble(y);
    printf ("mantissa of this number saved as double will be displayed by printf(%%.16e) as %.16e and exponent=%d\n", m, exp);

    y = ldexp ((1 + DBL_EPSILON)/2, DBL_MIN_EXP);
    m = frexp (y, &exp);
    printf ("the number (y) constructed from mantissa (1+DBL_EPSILON)/2 and exponent=DBL_MIN_EXP (%d) in binary form: ", DBL_MIN_EXP);
    DumpDouble(y);
    printf ("mantissa of this number saved as double will be displayed by printf(%%.16e) as %.16e and exponent=%d\n", m, exp);

    z = y - x;
    m = frexp (z, &exp);
    printf ("z=y-x in binary form: ");
    DumpDouble(z);
    printf ("z will be displayed by printf(%%.16e) as %.16e\n", z);
    printf ("z has mantissa=%.16e and exponent=%d\n", m, exp);

    if (x == y)
        printf ("\"if (x == y)\" say x == y\n");
    else
        printf ("\"if (x == y)\" say x != y\n");

    if ((x-y) == 0)
        printf ("\"if ((x-y) == 0)\" say \"(x-y) == 0\"\n");
    else
        printf ("\"if ((x-y) == 0)\" say \"(x-y) != 0\"\n");
}
```

This code produced following output:

```
DBL_MAX=1.7976931348623157e+308
DBL_MAX in binary form: 7FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF
DBL_MIN=2.2250738585072014e-308
DBL_MIN in binary form: 0010000000000000
DBL_MIN has mantissa=5.0000000000000000e-001 and exponent=-1021
mantissa of DBL_MIN in binary form: 3FE0000000000000
the number (x) constructed from mantissa 0.5 and exponent=DBL_MIN_EXP (-1021) in binary form: 0010000000000000
the number (y) constructed from mantissa 0.5000000000000001 and exponent=DBL_MIN_EXP (-1021) in binary form: 0010000000000001
mantissa of this number saved as double will be displayed by printf(%.16e) as 5.0000000000000011e-001 and exponent=-1021
the number (y) constructed from mantissa (1+DBL_EPSILON)/2 and exponent=DBL_MIN_EXP (-1021) in binary form: 0010000000000001
mantissa of this number saved as double will be displayed by printf(%.16e) as 5.0000000000000011e-001 and exponent=-1021
z=y-x in binary form: 0000000000000001
z will be displayed by printf(%.16e) as 4.9406564584124654e-324
z has mantissa=5.0000000000000000e-001 and exponent=-1073
"if (x == y)" say x != y
"if ((x-y) == 0)" say "(x-y) != 0"
```

So we can see, that if we work with numbers less then DBL_MIN, they will be not normalized (see `0000000000000001`). We are working with these numbers like with integers and without any "errors". Thus if we assign `y=x` then `if (x-y == 0)` is exactly so safe as `if (x == y)`, and `assert(x-x == 0)` works OK. In this example, z = 0.5 * 2 ^(-1073) = 1 * 2 ^(-1072). This number is really the smallest number which can we have saved in double. All arithmetical operation with numbers less DBL_MIN works like with integer multiplied with 2 ^(-1072).

So I has **no underflow** problems on my Windows 7 computer with Intel processor. **If somebody have another processor it would be interesting to compare our results**.

Have somebody an idea how one can produce arithmetic underflow with - or + operations? My experiments looks like so, that it is impossible.

**EDITED**: I modified the code a little for better readability of the code and the messages.

**ADDED LINKS**: My experiments shows, that http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/faq.html#underflow is absolutely correct on my Intel Core 2 CPU. The way how it will be calculated produce *no underflow* in "+" and "-" floating point operations. My results are independent on Strict (/fp:strict) or Precise (/fp:precise) Microsoft Visual C compiler switches (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb%28VS.80%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa289157)

**ONE MORE (PROBABLY THE LAST ONE) LINK AND MY FINAL REMARK**: I found a good reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_numbers, where is described the same what I written before. Including of denormal numbers or denormalized numbers (now often called subnormal numbers for example in In [IEEE 754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)) follow to following statment:

> “Denormal numbers provide the
>   guarantee that addition and
>   subtraction of floating-point numbers
>   never underflows; two nearby
>   floating-point numbers always have a
>   representable non-zero difference.
>   Without gradual underflow, the
>   subtraction a−b can underflow and
>   produce zero even though the values
>   are not equal.”

So all my results **must** be correct on any processor which supports IEEE 754-2008.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding what Mark says -- check out this link http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.18 . (Not sure if it applies to your situation though.)