# Incorrect long double calculation with GCC 4.4 on AIX 6.1

Tags: gcc, aix

The following program generates wrong output when compiled with GCC 4.4 under AIX 6.1, depending on optimization options

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const long double a = 2.0L;

    long double x = ::powl( a, a );
    printf( "  ::powl(2,2)=%Lf\n", x );

    long double y = std::pow( a, a );
    printf( "std::pow(2,2)=%Lf\n", y );

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled without optimization, the output is wrong:

```
  ::powl(2,2)=1.000000
std::pow(2,2)=1.000000
```

With -O or -mlong-double-64 the output is correct

```
  ::powl(2,2)=4.000000
std::pow(2,2)=4.000000
```

The problem does not exist in GCC 4.6 and GCC 4.7, however, I cannot esaily switch to a newer GCC version. An equivalent C program also works correctly with and without optimizations, so I assume there is something wrong with libstdc++.

Can anyone confirm this problem? This may be a related to [GCC problem with raw double type comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497825/gcc-problem-with-raw-double-type-comparisons).

Comment: http://ideone.com/qHAzBQ compiled on mingw32-g++.

Comment: Does `a` hold the correct value? What if you use `std::cout` to output the values instead of `printf`?

Comment: That does not help. Same output with std::cout. And yes, a=2.0.